# My changes made in Dashboard.vue aren't being saved (Laravel Jetstream Inertia.js)

Tags: laravel-8, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

This is my first day working with this so I'm not sure what's going on.

**When I start up my laravel project and add jetstream(inertia.js) and make changes to my resources/js/Dashboard.vue file, I open my local server and go to /dashboard and those changes don't appear on the website.**

Things I've tried:

- Made sure it wasn't my development server because I was able to change welcome.blade.php
- Ran npm run dev again.

Steps I made when I create the app:

```
1. ran laravel new ProjectName --jet
2. opened my project in VSCODE
3. ran npm install && npm run dev
4. Made changes to my Welcome.blade.php
5. Attempt at changing Dashboard.vue
```

Comment: same issue is happening with me. Even i have aslo cleared compiled view cache.

Comment: Check my response I found the solution.

Answer (score 2):

When you start your application, just type the following in your terminal.

```
 1. npm install
 2. npm run dev
 3. npm run prod
 4. npm run watch
 5. php artisan serve
```

And it should all work, for the question i had, all i used was steps. 1,2,4,5. But i ran into a problem later regarding something else and then ran npm run prod and it fixed.

Comment: It was really frustrating. Now I'll apply your solution and see if it works. Thanks .

Comment: hi, it didn't work for me. But I found the reason. This  is actually related to chrome cache. Everytime i manually cleared the cache the page, changes are displayed on the dashboard. I also confirmed by running in edge and opera browser. Everything was fine there.